# How to prevent child widget redraw when parent widget perform setState()?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a `ListView` inside many stateFull widget of tree, and i cant able to separate from all parent widget.
`Listview` build from `streambuilder`(firebase).
From a large hierarchy of stateFull widget, some of them anytime perform setState widget, then child ListView also redraw and once again it will get data from firebase and also its flickering(blinking)

explain below example

```
StatefullWidget(
  child:StatefullWidget(
    child:StatefullWidget(
      child:ListView()
    ),
  ),
);
```

There are three parent widget of Listview(), for user friendly app setState called many time in parent widget.

So i want to avoid flickering and redraw of listView(), even if the parent widget redraw(setState())

Comment: You should not be getting any data from Firebase in your `build` method. Instead you should load the data when the widget is initialized, and store/update it in the widget's state.

Comment: yes you are right, but what happen about redrawing of child widget ?

Comment: That shouldn't be causing reloading of the data as far as I know, but it's hard to be certain without seeing a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually calls the relevant Firebase API.

Comment: data is not reloading, ok problem solved but widget is redrawing when parent perform setstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector-class.html

'selector' of Provider is what you find.

But usually optimizing performance is enough for not blinking.
ListView.builder, const Widget, key, etc., https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html#performance-considerations

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the state management method.

For example with [getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package, you can make your widgets stateless and use getx widgets for any updating data.

This is the example of getx usage for default flutter app.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final controller = Get.put(Controller());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("counter")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            GetBuilder<Controller>(
                builder: (_) => Text(
                      'clicks: ${controller.count}',
                    )),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Next Route'),
              onPressed: () {
                Get.to(Second());
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: controller.increment(),  
          ),
    );
  }
}
class Second extends StatelessWidget {
  final Controller ctrl = Get.find();
  @override
  Widget build(context){
     return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("${ctrl.count}")));
  }
}
```